# Node.js callback not executed when using VSCode debugger

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have an issue with the VSCode Node.js debugger.

I have the following code (it downloads an image an calculates its hash):

```
var request = require('request');
var crypto = require('crypto');

request({ uri : 'http://static.wixstatic.com/media/28f6fa_1519eb247c97446098566248a9f86441.jpg', 
    encoding: null, 
    timeout: 10000 
    }, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(500).send(buildResponse(500, "Image download returned status code " + res.statusCode));
    }
    console.log(crypto.createHmac('sha256', body).digest('hex'));
});
```

If I run `node test.js`, it prints the hash of the file perfectly.
If I run it using VSCode debug mode, it does not.

If I set a break point at line 4 (`request({...`), the debugger hits the break point.
If I set a break point at line 8 (`if (err) { ...`), the debugger does not hit the break point.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

```
$ node -v
v4.6.0
```

VSCode version: 1.6.1 Recovery Build

Answer (score 1):

Just use the node-inspector it is for me the better way to debug code of backend

here is the link and there are complete guides to start witht that

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector

By the way is you want to debug some specific file use the node-debug

> node-debug my_file_to_debug.js

I hope it help you.